# `foreach` over parallelized collection never starts

Tags: multithreading, mongodb, scala, collections, parallel-processing

I have a Mongo database with jobs in it which I'd like to process in parallel; I thought of experimenting with parallel collections to handle the threading for me transparently (not that it would be significantly harder to use a thread pool). I came up with this code:

```
def run(stopSignal: SynchronizedQueue[Any]) = {
  val queue = new Iterator[Job] {
    private var prevId = new ObjectId("000000000000000000000000")

    def hasNext = stopSignal.isEmpty

    @tailrec
    def next = {
      val job = Job
        .where(_.status eqs Pending)
        // this works because the IDs start with a timestamp part
        .where(_._id gt prevId)
        .orderAsc(_.regTime)
        .get()
      job match {
        case Some(job) =>
          prevId = job.id
          println(s"next() => ${job.id}")
          job
        case None if hasNext =>
          Thread.sleep(500) // TODO: use a tailable cursor instead
          next
        case None =>
          throw new InterruptedException
      }
    }
  }

  try {
    queue.toStream.par.foreach { job =>
      println(s"processing ${job.id}...")
      processOne(job)
      println(s"processing complete: ${job.id}")
    }
  } catch { case _: InterruptedException => }
}
```

this produces:

```
next() => 53335f7bef867e6f0805abdb
next() => 53335fc6ef867e6f0805abe2
next() => 53335ffcef867e6f0805abe6
next() => 53336005ef867e6f0805abe7
next() => 53336008ef867e6f0805abe8
next() => 5333600cef867e6f0805abe9
```

but the processing never starts; i.e. the function passed to `foreach` is never invoked. If I remove the `.par` call, it works fine (but serially of course).

Which abstraction is leaking here exactly? How can I workaround it? Or should I just give up using parallel collections for this and move on to a more fool proof thread pool approach?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `par` method will firstly drain the elements of stream into an `ParSeq`.
So when you call `queue.toStream.par`. It will  traverse over the stream (calling the underlying iterator's `hasNext` and next method until iterator has no next). And after all jobs are retrieved, then it begins to call `processJob`

For Example

```
scala> (1 to 100).iterator.toStream
res7: scala.collection.immutable.Stream[Int] = Stream(1, ?)

scala> (1 to 100).iterator.toStream.par
res8: scala.collection.parallel.immutable.ParSeq[Int] = ParVector(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59, 60, 61, 62, 63, 64, 65, 66, 67, 68, 69, 70, 71, 72, 73, 74, 75, 76, 77, 78, 79, 80, 81, 82, 83, 84, 85, 86, 87, 88, 89, 90, 91, 92, 93, 94, 95, 96, 97, 98, 99, 100)
```

**the `par` method is not lazy**

If you just want your execution paralleled(actually it's already paralleled but not lazy):

- Group the stream into batches. call each batch's `par`.
- You could put the `processJob` method within a `Future` .
- Or you may consider using `actor` model to process such things
- use https://github.com/scalaz/scalaz-stream/

Comment: I was hoping to get lazy parallelized processing for free; I guess that won't be so easy after all :) I don't want actors for such a simple job (and I don't like Akka's dynamically typed actors anyway—typed channels didn't seem to have made it to the release); I'll see if I can combine `Future` and an appropriatly sized thread pool to achieve what I need in a simple `for` loop.

Comment: @jiljen: any idea where I could find a rational behind why `.par` is eager? it would make sense IMO for `.par` to be lazy on `Stream` (and `Iterator` if it were defined on it in the first place).

Comment: @ErikAllik I think the `Parallel` collection is very like normal collections expect its operations are paralleled. `.par` method create a `ParVector` which is an immutable collection, and have to know its elements in advance. I think over and  found you can group the stream into chunks. than call each's par method.

Comment: chunking won't help in my case, but anyway... was just wondering why parallel collections had to be limited to just `ParVector`; if you don't know, that's OK.

Comment: @ErikAllik Sorry, You may ask the question in scala user group.

Answer (score 0):

Ended up going for the thread pool approach; I'm still keeping @jilen's answer as the accepted one because he answered what I asked but I'm posting the solution as well:

Took the `BlockingExecutor` snippet (converted to Scala) from http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2013/11/throttling-task-submission-with-a-blockingexecutor-2.html (itself taken from [Java Concurrency in Practice](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Java-Concurrency-Practice-Brian-Goetz/dp/0321349601)) and then just used it directly bypassing any Scala/Future wrapping:

```
// 2 processing; 2 in the queue; 4 total
val executor = new BlockingExecutor(poolSize = 2, queueSize = 2)

try {
  queue.foreach { job =>
    executor.submit(new Runnable {
      def run = {
        println(s"processing ${job.id}...")
        processOne(job)
        println(s"processing complete: ${job.id}")
      }
    })
  }
} catch { case _: InterruptedException => }
executor.shutdown
```